# Strange behavior of undocumented RawArray and ArrayObject expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import, expression-manipulation, undocumented

I discovered several strange results and inconsistencies while trying to understand what undocumented `RawArray` and `ArrayObject` really are:

```
image = ImageResize[Import["http://wolfram.com/favicon.ico"][[1]], 1];

rawArray = ToBoxes[image][[1, 1, 1]]
(* RawArray[Byte, <1,1,4>] *)

rawArray // Head
(* RawArray *)

rawArray // Length
(* 2 *)

rawArray // InputForm
(* RawArray["Byte", {{{237, 153, 142, 255}}}] *)

Hold[RawArray]["Byte", {{{237, 153, 142, 255}}}] // Depth
(* 5 *)

rawArray // Depth
(* 2 *)

rawArray[[0]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification RawArray[Byte,<1,1,4>][[0]] is longer than depth of object. >> *)
(* RawArray *)

rawArray[[1]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification RawArray[Byte,<1,1,4>][[1]] is longer than depth of object. >> *)
(* "Byte" *)

arrayObject = rawArray[[2]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification RawArray[Byte,<1,1,4>][[2]] is longer than depth of object. >> *)
(* ArrayObject[Byte, <4>] *)

arrayObject // Head
(* Language`ArrayObject *)

arrayObject // AtomQ
(* True *)

wdx = ExportString[arrayObject, "WDX"];

ImportString[wdx, "WDX"]
(* {{{237, 153, 142, 255}}} *)

% // Head
(* List *)

Uncompress[Compress[arrayObject]]
(* {{{237, 153, 142, 255}}} *)

arrayObject // FullForm
(* List[List[List[237, 153, 142, 255]]] *)

arrayObject // InputForm
(* Raw[Language`ArrayObject, "78c4801b00000000"] *)

inputFormStr = ToString[arrayObject, InputForm]
(* "Raw[Language`ArrayObject, \"78c4801b00000000\"]" *)

heldArrayObject = ToExpression[inputFormStr, InputForm, Hold]
(* Hold[Raw[Language`ArrayObject, "78c4801b00000000"]] *)

heldArrayObject[[1, 0]]
(* Raw *)

heldArrayObject[[1, 1]]
(* Language`ArrayObject *)

heldArrayObject[[1, 2]]
(* "78c4801b00000000" *)

arrayObject2 = ReleaseHold[heldArrayObject]
(* 0 *)

arrayObject2 == 0
(* 0 == 0 *)

% // FullForm
(* Equal[1, 0] *)

ToBoxes[arrayObject2]
(* 0 *)

% // Head
(* Integer *)

arrayObject2 // Head
(* Language`ArrayObject *)

arrayObject2 // AtomQ
(* True *)

wdx = ExportString[arrayObject2, "WDX"];

reimported = ImportString[wdx, "WDX"]

(* Raw::string: String expected at position 2 in Raw[Language`ArrayObject,78 c4801b00000000]. >> *)
(* Raw[Language`ArrayObject, 78 c4801b00000000] *)

reimported // FullForm
(* Raw[Language`ArrayObject, Times[78, c4801b00000000]] *)

reimported // AtomQ
(* False *)

reimported // Depth
(* 3 *)

Uncompress[Compress[arrayObject2]]
(* "<---RAW DATA--->" *)

% // Head
(* String *)
```

Note that `Part` reports errors when invoked on a `RawArray`, but still is able to extract parts. `ArrayObject` has completely different representation in `InputForm` and `FullForm`, and turns into a `List` when reimported.

Is this behavior normal? Or there are some bugs? Is it because these parts were not supposed to ever be seen by humans?

Are there situations when one needs to explicitly construct or manipulate by `RawArray` or `ArrayObject` expressions? What is their real meaning?

Comment: An image in *Mathematica* is already *indivisible*! Try `AtomQ[image]` on your favicon. I assume the user is not supposed to use/see/care-about `RawArray`'s.

Comment: Can you make your question specific, rather than simply asking for comments?

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry, I was so surprised by results, that forget the rules. I formulated explicit questions that I'm interested in. Thanks!

Comment: @halirutan Yes, `Image` is atomic, but `GraphicsBox` or `RasterBox` are not.

Comment: I believe that this is not supposed to be used because `Image` (and the underlying arrays) are highly optimized for speed. Otherwise there would clearly be *any* documentation and someone would have used it in all the packages which come with *Mathematica*. Anyway, have you seen `image[[1, 2]] //Language\`FromArrayObject` and `Language\`NewArrayObject["Byte", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5}]`?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that an `ArrayObject` is literally just a thin wrapper around a C array that records its type and dimensions so that these can be passed around between the different image processing functions. AFAIK, there aren't any functions provided in the top-level language for manipulation of the `RawArray` type.

Comment: [Can you add anything?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133674/12)