# Extract RawArray from Audio

Tags: undocumented, sound, librarylink

[`Audio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) objects backed by in-memory data (not files) seem to contain a [`RawArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133666/12).

Is there a way to get the [`AudioData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioData.html) as an appropriate-type `RawArray`?

---

It could be done by forcing a change of representation, such as [passing through MathLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97332/12), `Uncompress[Compress[...], Hold]`, or similar. None of these is fast.

It could be done by just using AudioData and re-packing the result into a RawArray. This wasted memory.  The typical audio representation uses 16-bit integers.  Converting this to 64-bit integers or reals increases the storage requirements by a factor of 4.

---

Motivation:

Currently, there is no direct way to exchange `Audio` objects with C code through LibraryLink, but there is a way to send/receive `RawArray`s.

This is not a problem for the similar `Image`/`Image3D` (also likely backed by `RawArray`) because that is directly supported by LibraryLink (`MImage`).

`RawArray`s can be converted to `Audio` using `Audio[ra, ...]`.

Comment: Is there no way to unpack it with AudioData and then convert to RawArray?

Comment: Something like ``Audio`InternalAudioData``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal function `` Audio`InternalAudioData `` could be used to accomplish this, subject to the usual caveats concerning *undocumented* functionality.

```
Audio`InternalAudioData[Audio[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]

(* RawArray["Real32", <1, 4>] *)

Audio`InternalAudioData[Audio["ExampleData/car.mp3"]]

(* RawArray["Real32", <1, 328320>] *)
```