# How to convert a RawArray of bytes to ByteArray?

Tags: list-manipulation, undocumented, conversion, internals

A `ByteArray` can be converted to a [`RawArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133666/12):

```
ba = ByteArray[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(* ByteArray[{1, 2, 3, 4}] *)

ra = RawArray["Byte", ba]
(* RawArray["UnsignedInteger8",{1, 2, 3, 4}] *)

Normal[ra]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Presumably, this is done without unpacking the ByteArray contents to 64-bit integers first (although I have no proof of this).

Is there a similar space-efficient way to convert a rank-1 byte-type `RawArray` to a `ByteArray`?

Comment: The CURLLink package reveals that `"ByteArray"` is a valid type specification for LibraryFunctionLoad. If anyone is willing to investigate this, it may lead to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At present there is no way to do this from top level, since there is no interface to the internal function that converts a rank-1 `RawArray` of bytes into a `ByteArray`.

However, as already pointed out, it's possible to take advantage of LibraryLink which will do a conversion given an `MRawArray` on the C side and a `"ByteArray"` return type, for example

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  #include \"WolframRawArrayLibrary.h\"

  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion() {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return 0;
  }

  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int mrawarray_to_bytearray( WolframLibraryData libData, 
    mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {

    WolframRawArrayLibrary_Functions rawFuns = libData->rawarrayLibraryFunctions;
    MRawArray ra;
    mint rank;
    rawarray_t type;

    if (Argc != 1) return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    ra = MArgument_getMRawArray(Args[0]);

    type = rawFuns->MRawArray_getType(ra);
    rank = rawFuns->MRawArray_getRank(ra);

    if (rank == 1 && type == MRawArray_Type_Ubit8) {
      MArgument_setMRawArray(Res, ra);
      return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    } 
    return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;

  }";

lib = CreateLibrary[src, "toByteArray"];

toByteArray = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, 
  "mrawarray_to_bytearray", {"RawArray"}, "ByteArray"];

toByteArray[RawArray["Byte", {1, 2, 3, 4}]]

(* ByteArray["AQIDBA=="] *)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I meant to try this, but haven't gotten to it yet, and I really didn't expect it to be as simple as returning an MRawArray as type "ByteArray".

Comment: I was trying to find out which is the earliest version in which this works, so I tried it in 10.4 (first version with RawArray support in LibraryLink). In that version, it only starts working after `ByteArray` has been used at least once. I.e. if I evaluate `ByteArray[{0}]` before I try `toByteArray`, everything is fine. If I don't the first evaluation of `toByteArray[RawArray["Byte", {1, 2, 3, 4}]]` returns `ByteArray[""]` (from the second onwards, everything is fine).

Comment: Sounds like a bug (fixed in 11.0).

Comment: Well, it's undocumented, so I wasn't expecting much :-) I also noticed that trying to pass a `ByteArray` argument using `"Constant"` passing crashes the kernel.

Answer (score 7):

The new in M12 function [`NumericArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericArray) is essentially the documented version of the undocumented [`RawArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawArray). The conversions between [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray) and [`NumericArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericArray) are straightforward:

```
ba = ByteArray[{1,2,3,4}];
ba //InputForm
```

> ByteArray["AQIDBA=="]

Conversion to a [`NumericArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericArray):

```
na = NumericArray[ba, "Byte"];
na //InputForm
```

> NumericArray[{1, 2, 3, 4}, "UnsignedInteger8"]

Conversion back to a [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray):

```
ba === ByteArray @ na
```

> True

Note that your [`RawArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawArray) syntax is still supported, but it now constructs a [`NumericArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericArray) object instead:

```
RawArray["Byte", ba] //InputForm
```

> NumericArray[{1, 2, 3, 4}, "UnsignedInteger8"]