# WXF encoder library for C++

Tags: interoperability, c++

WXF is [a fully documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html) binary encoding for Wolfram Language expressions. WRI has already published [a Python encoder/decoder](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython) for this format. [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) also uses it.

**Has anyone developed a WXF *encoder* for C++?**

Unlike in Python, in C++ there's no standard set of data structures to use to represent a WL expression. Therefore I expect that eventually there will be several C++ WXF libraries, backed by different data structures and intended for different uses.

The specific use case I have in mind here is returning complex results from LibraryFunctions that cannot be simply represented as an MTensor. The typical solution for this is using MathLink. I suspect that encoding those results to WXF, [transferring them as a ByteArray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159996/12), then decoding with [`BinaryDeserialize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryDeserialize.html) will be faster, in some cases much faster, than using MathLink. This suspicion is based on noticing that [sometimes, even encoding to JSON and transferring as a string can be faster than using MathLink](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/575100).

Comment: The original internal WXF library was written in C. There were plans to open-source it.

Comment: One cool thing this would provide is the means to use JLink (or more relevant to me, PJLink) with WXF instead of MathLink as it’s then just basically a matter of handling the type-decoding and encoding intelligently. Nothing else about JLink really *needs* MathLink. This could be then be reasonably easily extended to languages like Julia, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have developed a C library to support `BinarySerialize`/`BinaryDeserialize`. I confirm that we plan to open-source it as well.

The library is built around a struct, called `WXFExpr`, that can represent any WXF types. It decodes a stream of WXF bytes into a stream of `WXFExpr`, which can be seen as an intermediary representation, ensuring the encoding is consistent with WXF specifications.

It's then up to the caller of the library to turn these `WXFExpr` into something meaningful. That's exactly what the Wolfram Kernel does for `BinaryDeserialize`.

Similarly during serialization the library turns `WXFExpr` into a consistent stream of WXF bytes. The caller fills the `WXFExpr` with relevant data.

Comment: How does the `BinarySerialize`/WXF pipeline compare to MathLink performance wise in terms of transmitting huge packed arrays?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I believe MathLink does very well with huge packed arrays. It's almost as fast as copying the array as many times as necessary for the transfer. I expect a WXF-based transfer to do better than MathLink with complex expressions or non-packed arrays. There's also the extra benefit of transparency: since the format is documented, it is very clear what can be done with it. See all the spelunking we did a month ago just to determine if the expression on the MathLink link (1) is a packed array (2) its type. With WXF no spelunking is needed.

Comment: @Szabolcs true, but depending on *how much* better MathLink is it might still be worth having some well-designed MathLink stuff lying around. The decoding issue is not great, but can be handled pretty cleanly on the Mathematica side by providing some extra data (e.g. wrapping the packed array data with some fake head like `PackedArray`). This is basically the idea JLink uses. Some kind of intelligent type decoder (and maybe encoder, to make things like `Graph` transmit cleanly) will be necessary in the end for WXF formats anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, if the performance hit is relatively small, then I can imagine just ditching MathLink whenever possible. In any case, the benchmark would be nice to have.

Comment: @Dorian Is there any updates regarding completion of this C library?

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately we didn't have the bandwidth to perform the library release yet. It's still something that we want to do though.

Comment: Another ping on this. Is it still a good idea to build on WXF for the future? My plan was to replace all use of MathLink with transferring WXF-encoded bytes. Does this sound like a good idea, i.e. is WXF going to be well supported in the future?