# WXF encoder library for C++ (asking on may 2019)

Tags: interoperability, c++

Is there any updates regarding plans to open-source C library to support WXF?

My question is related to ["WXF encoder library for C++"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184332/wxf-encoder-library-for-c). Strongly apologize for opening a new question regarding this but I cannot add comments to original one due to low reputation.

Comment: @Jason, The original answer was published half a year ago. Today is a may 2019 and I would like to ask if the library is still under development. Could you please ask a status of development in the original question?