# NumericArray versus PackedArray in MMA12

Tags: data-types

I just tried to understand the differences between `NumericArray` and `PackedArray` in MMA12. The memory footprint of a `NumericArray` appears to be less than for a `PackedArray`. However, what is the use of the `NumericArray`, if simple matrix multiplication of `NumericArray`s

```
A.B
```

returns unevaluated? In fact, `Flatten[]` works with `NumericArray[]` but `Dot[]` does not.

So, can someone explain to me the purpose and/or use of `NumericArray[]`?

Comment: Some details here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49966830#49966830

Comment: It is not accurate to refer to packed arrays as `PackedArray`. There is no such head. A packed array is just an alternative storage format for `List`s with machine-representable numeric elements, not an expression type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`NumericArray`s are unrelated to packed arrays.

"Packed array" refers to an internal efficient storage format used for `List`s. There is no such head as `PackedArray`.  Normally, packed arrays are not observable. Their usage is completely transparent. The only way to tell that a `List` is packed is either by performance measurements or by using some special developer functions (such as `PackedArrayQ`).

`NumericArray`s are an expression type in their own right.

`NumericArray` basically just provides a space-efficient and exact storage format. On a typical modern system, Mathematica stores both machine integers and machine reals in 64 bits.  Even if you use [`BinaryRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryRead.html) to read a file byte-by-byte, 64-bits will be wasted for storing each byte. Clearly, 8 bits would be enough. `NumericArray` enables that, not only for bytes, but for all typical integer and floating point formats.

`NumericArray` is not really useful for *computation* at this point. It is useful as an *exchange format*. It can wrap raw arrays in C, so it is useful with LibraryLink. [There's a LibraryLink API for it in M12.0.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MNumericArray_new.html)  It can be serialized to [WXF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html), which is partially used by `ExternalEvaluate` to communicate with Python.  It appears in the InputForm of `Image` and `Audio`, thus serializing these atomic expressions into a compound one will not waste any space.

If you want to do computations, you'd do one of the following:

- Extract the values from the `NumericArray` using `Normal` (and thus increase the memory usage)
- Put it in a computable format like `Image` or `Audio`
- As a special case, neural net functions handle numeric arrays efficiently. You can give one as input to e.g. a linear layer and get another one as output.
- Write your own functions in C to handle them (LibraryLink). It is a convenience for C programmers to use NumericArray because now they can choose their own data format and have Mathematica adapt to it, rather than having to adapt to Mathematica's format.

Perhaps in the future more functions will handle numeric arrays without needing to extract data from them.

---

`NumericArray` did exist in previous versions in the form of [the undocumented `RawArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133666/12). I believe these are the same thing as the LibraryLink RawArray API works with NumericArrays and vice versa. Also, old RawArrays now always appear as NumericArray in M12.0. The syntax of `NumericArray` is slightly different from the old `RawArray` though.

Comment: Thx, I am looking for a way to implement `NumericArray` in 11.3. Now it partly works. ```NumericArray[x_, y_String] := RawArray[y, x];
NumericArray[x_, y_String, method_String] := NumericArray[x, y];```